# Jmeter increasing request per second

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

So, I'd run test which is sending

1. 0-10 min - 0,25 request per second
2. 10-20 min 1 request per second
3. 20-30min  1,75 request per second

So every 10 min I'd like to add 0,75 request per second fix six hours increasing it every 10 min/0,75 request per second.

I'm trying with Stepping Thread Group and with Concurrency Thread Group but I'm not sure what's the best for me. Any suggestions?

[my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHnu1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track. Optionally, you can also have a look at [Ultimate thread group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which gives you finer control on ramp-up and ramp-down.

Check the output in Aggregate report if the Throughput is as per your expectations. Reply to this thread if otherwise and we can have a further look.

Answer (score 0):

I think Concurrency Thread Group is a good choice, but "the best for you" would be using it in conjunction with the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) so:

- Concurrency Thread Group provides threads (virtual users)
- Throughput Shaping Timer ensures that the users send exactly desired number of requests per second

You can connect these 2 guys together using [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so it would be possible for JMeter to kick off some new threads if the current amount is not enough to reach/maintain the desired number of requests per second

Comment: So I've tried with Throughput Shaping Timer. And as I understand function should send 0.25 request per second = one request per 4 second = 15 request per minute. But in agregate report I have only 12. What I'm missing?

Screenshot posted above in comment

Answer (score 0):

So I've tried with Throughput Shaping Timer.
And as I understand function should send 0.25 request per second = one request per 4 second = 15 request per minute.
But in agregate report I have only 12. What I'm missing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Irm.png)